# Query just day month year from now()

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am inserting a date into a database with `NOW()` then I query the result. Here is the code.

```
    function get_content($id = ''){

if($id != ''):
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cms_content WHERE id = '$id'";

    $return = '<p><a href="index.php">Back to Content</a></p>';
else:
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cms_content ORDER BY id DESC";
endif;

    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($res) != 0):
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            echo '<h1><a href="index.php?id=' . $row['id'] . ' "> ' . $row['title'] . '</a></h1>';
            echo '<p>' . stripslashes($row['body']) . '</p>';
            **echo '<p>' . $row['date_posted'] . '</p>';**
            }
    else:
        echo '<p> You broke it!, this post dosn\'t exsist!';
    endif;

    echo $return;
```

The

```
echo '<p>' . $row['date_posted'] . '</p>';
```

is where I echo the date. When I echo this from the database I get 2012-07-25 19:00:46, because that's what is in the database. My question is how would I echo the day, then echo the month, then the year. Ideally these would all be separate echos so I could style each differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the format is known, you can simply use this:

```
list($year,$month,$day) = explode("-",substr($row['date_posted'],0,10));
```

Then you can echo those variables however you want.

Answer (score 2):

This is alot more handy and less code.

```
$date = new DateTime($row['date_posted']);
$day = date->format('d');
$month = date->format('F');
$year = date->format('Y');
```

Resource: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = strtotime($row['date_posted'];
echo date('d', $date);
echo date('m', $date);
echo date('Y', $date);
```

or

```
$date = new DateTime($row['date_posted']);
echo $date->format('Y');
```

etc

Comment: Why would you not write the date out all in one line/function call.

Comment: strtotime doesn't always do what you expect. Converting the date to a human readable format then converting it back into a tme before converting it into a different human readable format is a bit silly. Converting the date using UNIX_TIMESTAMP() in the query will be less buggy - but still is the same transformation.

Comment: because he said "Ideally these would all be separate echos so i could style each differently. "

Answer (score 0):

You would use `php` built in `date()` function: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
echo "<p>".date('j M, Y', $row['date_posted'])."</p>";
// would output <p>25 July, 2012</p>
```

This can be modified into just about any format that you would like.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to do that directly in SQL, using the *date_format* function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format